# Auto logout in DNN, once browser is closed

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am developing an application using DNN. One of the requirements are to automatically logout a User if he closes his browser clicking on the Close button. I have tried many ways but its not working? Any suggestions, how this can be implemented.

Comment: When I enter `Auto logout in DNN, once browser is closed` I get one discussion specifically about this (and others for other platforms.) Which ways have you tried and what is not working about it?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - If a browser is closed, Users should automatically logout from the application and when they start application again, they must be asked to login.

Comment: I understand. You should be more specific about what you have tried already. Google your search title, there are resources on it on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable the "remember me" option in the Host Settings, DNN will log users out once the browser session is closed (close all windows).

Is that what you need to ensure?